# Split a table due to clearness, maintainability?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

#### Does it make sense to split a table just for the sake of clearness, maintainability?

I have a classic user table, which amongst others stores data like the following

```
userid  name        userName        email            lastlogin      
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
1       Buffer      Stack           s@overflow.com   1312565858
```

Additionally I need to persist settings on a per user basis. These settings will cover mostly boolean fields and might look like this.

```
quickSave   showInfo    showOnlineStatus    sendNews         sendRemainder      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
0           1           1                   1                0
```

That being said, I see at least the two (usual) options

- add the individual settings directly to the user table
- create a separate settings table and persist the relation

My tendency to structure things leads me to latter.

### Question

Is it a valid approach to split tables, if they are strictly 1-to-1 related like the above and if so, is there a threshold, when to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preference is the base my spilts on read/write activity.

For example

If your user table is only going to WRITTEN infrequently but READ frequently the I would separate it from the settings table which may be WRITTEN more frequently.

This is more critical if you are using myISAM tables as they have table level locking. InnoDB uses row level locking ( but you can still lock tables as a whole )  but still its nice to be able to have the option move storage around based on read/write frequency

Comment: +1 : This is a very strong factor in transactional data processing.  Keep as much data free to be accessed/modified as often ans for as long as possible.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that "it depends" is the only completely true answer that can be given.
- The question is kind of like asking "is 6th normal form better than 5th normal form?"

The benefit of seperate tables is predominantly flexibility:
- The ability to make design changes with minimal impact

For example, you may want to start maintaining old values as well as current values, the less tightly coupled everything is, the easier to make the change.

But the extreme version of that would be to have a seperate table for every single field.  And I can't see many people suggesting that That would be a good idea.  Especially from a maintainability stand-point; it may be flexible, but having a billion tables is far from easy to understand.

My basic rule of thumb about when to use a seperate table is when the fields can be logically considered significantly different.  Details about a user (name, address, etc) and their applciation settings (quick save, etc) seems to fit that bill well enough to me.  It may not matter here, but you then potentially avoid contention where one process is trying to process user addresses, and another is updating user application settings.

That said, if you find that you *always* join two tables together before the data is usable, it's a strong indicator that they shouldn't be kept separate.  And I suspect you may use these tables by looking up the user's login details in one, and joining to the other.

My personal choice in your case, from the narrow perspective of this question?
- Keep them together in one table
- Until you ever find a reason not to

You can always separate them out later, and recombine them in a view, to maintain code compatibility.

Comment: The broader view of my comment. +1 for the comment about joins ( and a pox and those who think joins are free ) which is my 2nd determinate for splits and combines

Answer (score 2):

I would choose a third option:

Create an `authentication` table that stores information like `lastLogin`, `userName`, etc. and THEN add all these columns to the `user` table.

This information **does** describe the user, so in the interest of maintaining database *entities*, I would add the columns to the `user` table.

On the other hand, if there's a well defined boundary around an entity you could describe as `settings`, then there's nothing wrong with 1-to-1 relationships.

Comment: So, your suggestion is to have either two (user and authentication) or three tables (user, authentication and settings)?

Comment: I tend to think there's enough data with user logins that the data would warrant a special table for authentication. That's just me. You can make that decision yourself. I think, however, that these settings are user-specific and thus part of the user entity. To that end, I would store them on the user table. **If** you store the settings on the user table, I would create the authentication table, just to keep that table from getting out of hand. **If** you choose to create a special table for the settings, then the authentication table is up to you, since the user table won't be too messy.

Answer (score 2):

Database theory can get really out of control in a hurry.  The answer is to be reasonable when making a decision.

True, hardcore DBA's would argue that an email doesn't belong in a user table because the user could have multiples....and could change....and you could have to keep a history....etc.  In reality, it's silly.  If your app only requires one email address, it works for you.  The point is, there's more to making these decisions than solely theory.

Similarly, in actual practice either solution you proposed is going to work.  None is going to have a dramatic difference on performance.  If it was me, I'd likely save it to a separate table that has all user preferences to include other UI elements as well.  Again, it's up to you and your needs.

Comment: I disagree - I believe that Theory CAN solve these kinds of questions.  The problem is that the Theory is complex, the Specification often not tightly definable, and the effort often impractical.  Understanding the theory, however, allows us to make informed judgements rather than calculations.  We decide what we need to account for (today or in the future), and so what theory to include in our decision making, and what to ignore.  Then we flip a coin and ask someone else to decide for us any way ;)

Comment: @bpeterson76 Not sure why you blame "theory" or "hardcore DBAs" for failing to implement requirements properly. Design theory would surely say that you should represent the reality of the situation accurately. Maybe you've just had some bad experiences with DBAs or people who didn't know enough about design theory.

Comment: @dportas I've actually had very good experiences with DBA's and consider several to be my most productive and knowledgable coworkers.  Overdoing things isn't just limited to DBA's.  It's just that DB theory is more absolute than things like UI design, so it's an easier example to cite.  For example, when I go to a client and bid a site, I will often hold back on a fully customized CMS or CRM when they're small and off-the-shelf might even be overkill.  The point is, identify the need, develop a solution, review, and deploy.  No need to build an enterprise-grade system for 10 visitors a week.

Answer (score 2):

You have a trade-off. You currently have a series of things that are in a one-to-one relationship to a user. By keeping them in the same table you make them easier to query but more difficult when you want to add another field. By adding a settings table, you may make the data more difficult to query and possibly create a performance nightmare depending on the design.

You could go about creating the table in two ways, making a table that is in a one-to-one relationship to the users. This is fine if your users table is already very wide and you don't need these settings in most queries of the users tables. This can also be good if you have a situation where things are 1-1 now, but you expect them to become 1-many later. You still have to alter the table if you need to add a new setting though.

The alternative method is to create an EAV table that contains something like Userid, SettingType, Value. This is a very poor method for storing for querying most data. Now instead of querying one table, you need to query the first table and join to the second table multiple times to get all the data. And you may not even know in advance how many times to join. This structure should be used sparingly and never for settings that you know you will need in advance. It's proper use is for client-defined fields. And then only if you expect to rarely use it. It is a performance killer.

Comment: EAV - a necessary model for extremely annoying values :)